# Is it possible to get members with YouTube API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a Discord server application that can only be joined by people who have subscribed to a YouTube channel membership.
However, no matter how much I search, I can't find any API information related to membership.
I need your support if you don't mind

I used chatGPT and looked it up on "YouTube API members" etc.

Comment: To clarify [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453248/is-it-possible-to-get-members-with-youtube-api#comment134809773_76454844), does membership require users to pay something to become a member? Or you're talking about regular free subscriptions?

Comment: I'm talking about paid subscriptions not recurring free subscriptions
I'm Japanese and I don't know what to say there

Comment: Is the channel you're mentioning yours (like you can login on YouTube with this channel) or one of someone else?

Comment: what i envision
First, log in with google etc.
Next, get the list etc. that person is registered for membership
Allow participation if there is a specific channel in it
is that.

Comment: My idea was to web-scrape the YouTube UI but as I don't fulfill the requirements to join the YouTube Partner Program, I can't help you more sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no endpoint for the YouTube Data API that will tell you who has subscribed to your channel or any channel for that matter.

TBH the Data API is very limited.

Comment: When I say subscribed, does that mean I signed up for a membership?

Comment: When i say subscribed i mean clicked the subscribed button on your channel, signed up for member ship or even clicked the notification icon.   The api does not tell you anything about those users.

Answer (score 0):

Discord has a built-in feature to connect with YouTube Membership.

You can read more here: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/215162978-YouTube-Channel-Memberships-Integration-FAQ